How to call a process flow with Rule Unit in drools 8
I have a drl with Rule unit and I created a Person model class and PersonUnit java class.
I created a test class to test the drl (using instance.fire()) which is working fine . Now I have added a BPMN flow with a task and pointed Rule unit of drl in RuleFlow Group (unit:resources.com.example.PersonUnit) .
How should we invoke the ruleflow ? Like in traditional way we dont have ksession.startProcess(processId);
Using Quarkus , a REST end point will be generated automatically, so we can test the flow using REST end point. But, without Quarkus , how to invoke the flow ?
I understand With traditional approach we cannot invoke the flow when we are using Rule unit. Please suggest me .
